# RestKit ObjectLoader Unrecognized Selector trying to map objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit, unrecognized-selector

This issue is specific to **RestKit**, but I believe the underlying issue is related to registering to notifications. I could really use some help figuring this one out...I seem to be having the same issue appearing multiple times:

An `NSInvalidArguementException` coming from 
**`serviceDidBecomeUnavailableNotification`** within `RKClient`.  The action 
is calling from `__NSMallocBlock__`,  `__NSCFString`, `__NSCFArray`, `NSURL`, 
and `UICFFont`... obviously the delegate is not being set correctly.

It is ONLY in my requests using `RKObjectMapping` to map the response to 
my model classes.  I've noticed the `objectLoader` has 
`isResponseMappable` and checks `[self.response isServiceUnavailable]` - 
which then posts a `RKServiceDidBecomeUnavailableNotification`.  This 
seems to be where my issue is coming from.  The only place I see 
`isResponseMappable` being called is within `didFinishLoad:(RKResponse*)response`.

Here's an example stack trace, I thought this could be very beneficial:

```
Error Message: 
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSMallocBlock__ 
serviceDidBecomeUnavailableNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent 
to instance 0xee168b0 

CoreFoundation:2:in `0x37d4dacb -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] 
+ 174' 
CoreFoundation:3:in `0x37d4c945 ___forwarding___ + 300' 
CoreFoundation:4:in `0x37ca7680 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48' 
Foundation:5:in `0x31c6f50f __57-[NSNotificationCenter 
addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 18' 
CoreFoundation:6:in `0x37d16577 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 
+ 70' 
CoreFoundation:7:in `0x37ca20cf _CFXNotificationPost + 1406' 
Foundation:8:in `0x31be33fb -[NSNotificationCenter 
postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66' 
Foundation:9:in `0x31be4c2b -[NSNotificationCenter 
postNotificationName:object:] + 30' 
MyApp:10:in `0x000d2157 -[RKObjectLoader isResponseMappable] + 114' 
MyApp:11:in `0x000d2b83 -[RKObjectLoader didFinishLoad:] + 418' 
MyApp:12:in `0x000cb151 -[RKResponse connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 
36' 
Foundation:13:in `0x31ca6c39 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal 
_withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 16' 
Foundation:14:in `0x31bfe6e9 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection 
invokeForDelegate:] + 28'
```

If anyone has any helpful tips, ideas, or suggestions on how to debug this, it would be **greatly** appreciated!  I've been dealing with this for two weeks and am **only** seeing it in deployed apps (cannot replicate the issue) so any insight is better than none!  Cheers!

Comment: Which version of RestKit do you use? Download from webpage or git/master?

Comment: download from webpage (v0.9.3)

Comment: I've had similar reports from one of my apps, but the problems went away when i upgraded to github/master version of RestKit.

Comment: Thanks, mja.  I will try that this afternoon.  I was hesitant to include from the master branch as I didn't know what issues could potentially arise from doing so, but maybe that's my best solution.  I'll be sure to let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase any others fall onto this solution, the approach I took was:

**Completely** remove `RestKit` from my existing project.  I then downloaded the master branch of RestKit, reintegrated into my project (there were some deprecated methods, less necessary frameworks, and refactored classes, but all in all pretty simple).  I will be releasing this version with the new RestKit within the next week or so, and **HOPE** to not see this issue arising again.:)

If I do have this issue, I will come back and modify my answer with a reason for why it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have add all the frame works recommended for RestKit, in your project

```
1. **CFNetwork.framework**
1. **CoreData.framework**
1. **MobileCoreServices.framework**
1. **SystemConfiguration.framework**
1. **libxml2.dylib**
```

Comment: Yep, definitely have all the frameworks!

The app works as needed with 0.9.3 other than this minor hiccup.  I've had it live for almost 2 months with my newest update and this is the only issue I'm seeing from anywhere in my app.  That makes me think it couldn't be a linking issue, but rather the way the objectLoader is handling invalid mapping responses...  Thanks for the thought, though!

Any others are GREATLY appreciated - I'd really like to find the root cause of this one!